# Distribution analysis "too uniform" - need help understanding my result

Tags: distributions, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I have $n>1000$ vectors of size $k=20$, sampled from an unknown source that I would like to find their distribution.
They appear uniform, so I run the KS test with $\alpha=0.1$ to check.
If this were indeed uniform, then I would get about $0.1 n$ rejects, and just for evaluation, this is what I get from simulated vectors sampled from a known uniform distribution.

However, performing the KS test on my data, I get only $0.04n$ rejects. What does this mean? can this mean there is some structure in my data, causing the samples to have different values in about the same probability? i.e. they are not generated by an i.i.d uniform source, but are rather spanned to fill the entire range of values?

I will appreciate any insights on this subject.

Comment: Please describe exactly how you are running a KS test on each vector. In particular, do you know the range of this uniform distribution beforehand or are you estimating it from the values in the vectors?

Comment: I know the range of the distribution. My data dictates a certain range. I evaluate the KStest function in MATLAB (I did not write it myself), and I use a densely-sampled numerical expression (derived from the analytic expression) for uniform CDF. Trying with different sampling rated for the CDF yields the same results, although since the size of each vector is small I don't think I benefit from using a large number of sampled points from the uniform CDF.

Comment: This way of running a KS test is strange, because sampling from a uniform CDF isn't necessary. But the issue isn't whether there are bugs in KSTest, but rather in whether you have correctly applied and interpreted it. So far it looks fine. What does the empirical CDF of all $nk$ numbers look like? Is it extremely close to diagonal, running from end of your range to the other? Any deviations from that would indicate systematic variations from uniformity among the $n$ vectors.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by 'diagonal', but I ran it now and the CDF for the all vectors together indeed looks like an analytical expression for a uniform distribution in my specified range.

Comment: It is strange how you keep referring to an "analytical expression"--it makes me wonder whether we understand "uniform" in the same sense. The CDF for a uniform distribution is *linear* over the range of the distribution, rising from $0$ to $1$ (which is what I mean by "diagonal"). Anyway, if it's possible these data are *too* uniform, you might want to double-check that with a chi-squared test and report the *left* tail probability (instead of the right tail probability).

Comment: Our definition for the uniform CDF are the same - that is what I mean by analytical expression. I am beginning to wonder, looking at the data, whether my data is somehow symmetric, which will indeed increase the "uniformity" of it relative to a true uniform distribution. I will examine this further. Thank you!